# Why is it that the preview in the video editor is different from the render?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm making a video for my Youtube, don't ask why I use blender for it, but for some reason the preview is completely different from the render output. In my video, I used one long clip and cut it into many pieces while in edit, but in the render, it seems blender just used the original clip playing, without the cuts. This is weird because all the other effects I have work as I wanted, but the this clip here doesn't seem to match the render at all. Here, the render (frame 2189) is seen next to the preview of the same frame. Why is it different?
(Ill also note that switching to older versions like 2.7 fix this issue.)
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug…

Comment: Check your source file if it has vfr(variable frame rate) in MediaInfo: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo If this is the case you'll have to convert it to cfr and then select all of strips one by one and change the source file in the sidebar source panel.  Most NLE's can't deal with vfr, and needs the footage converted either internally or externally to cfr.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this issue in Blender 3.0. It was due to the screen recording footage I had being a variable frame rate.

You can check if yours has variable frame rate (and amend it to be constant) using `ffmpeg`

Checking if you have variable frame rate: https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/check-video-variable-framerate-on-windows-10/

Fixing it: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate

Comment: I think I figured it out actually. I'll try to explain it in an answer

Comment: Awesome, this worked! I found that the audio didn't quite sync up with the video when I converted a variable frame rate to a constant 30. However I managed to get around this issue with multiple cuts. Any ideas as to why the audio is not synced?

Comment: It may be that your video wasn't 30fps. I think mine ended up at something like 29.94fps, which over a longer period of time would get out of sync

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in the Properties tab, on the icon that looks like a printer, at the Post Processing section if either the Compositing or Sequencer box is checked?

The Compositing outputs the Compositor Editor or the 3D Viewport camera while the Sequencer outputs the VSE/Video Sequencer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out i think. I was using 100% proxies, and for some reason the proxy footage didn't match the actual footage after I edited the proxy.